# How can I convert dates in string in multiple format to date type in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, data-science

I have a date column which stores date in multiple formats like:

```
Date
11/07/2016 12:30:00
07-11-2016 12:30:00
11/08/2016 12:30:00
08-11-2016 12:30:00
```

For example, the first two dates mean 11th November 2016

How can I format these dates to date type in pandas to get the same date from multiple formats?

For example:

```
Timestamp
11/07/2016    12:30
13-11-2016 12:30:00
11/08/2016 11:35:00
08-12-2016     7:18
```

Output:

```
Date        Time
07-11-2016  12:30:00
13-11-2016  12:30:00
08-11-2016  11:35:00
08-12-2016  07:18:00
```

The formats are different here, but for each format, day appears first, then month and lastly year.

Comment: No, it's different. I have dates in the different format of timestamps and needed to be converted to one

Comment: Thanks, i got the way- pd.to_datetime(df["Timestamp"], dayfirst=True)

Comment: "the first two dates mean 11th November 2016".  No, they either mean 11th July, 2016 or 7th November, 2016.  Which is it?

Comment: First two date means 11th July 2016 and 7th November 2016

Comment: @MarkTolonen- Anyway I have already added the answer in my previous comment